# Bind page title to a text block in a style

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, styles

OK, I have defined a style for Navigation Window. I have successfully styled Navigation buttons and even added page breadcrumbs to the Navigation menu. What I want is to add Page title next to the breadcrumbs:

```
Style x:Key="{x:Type NavigationWindow}" TargetType="NavigationWindow">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="NavigationWindow">
                <DockPanel Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}">
                ...
                <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="16"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        ....
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="4" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Gray"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Text="{Binding Path=Title,
                                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                                  AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DockPanel>
    ...
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

The binding doesn't work for the last TextBlock. (However it works just fine if not used within a style, but in regular XAML page code-behind) I have no idea why. Help? How to make it display the current page title? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that within the `ControlTemplate`, there is no ancestor of type `Page`. *The control you apply the template to* may have an ancestor of type Page, but the `ControlTemplate` itself doesn't know about that. It only knows about ancestors in its own logical tree.

To help mitigate this issue, the WPF designers added the [**TemplateBinding**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742882.aspx) markup extension, which allows you to apply the value of a property on the templated control to a property in the control template.

So, on the `NavigationWindow`, you should create a property that exposes the `Title` of the `Page`. Then you can use the following mark-up to bind to it:

```
Text="{TemplateBinding TitleProperty}"
```

Comment: Let me be more specific: 
I have set the setter 
<Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}} />
This exposes the title of the Navigation Window, which is the same as Page.WindowTitle. However, what I need is the Page.Title property. Can you help?